# "Pivoting" a key|value table using case returns blank columns... mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot, key-value

I am trying to transform data in key|value format into one line per entry. The source DB is mysql and I know that I need to use Case statements in order to pivot, and have followed some examples on this site to construct my query.

However, I am only getting back one column of data with blanks in the remaining columns.

Source table format

| user_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first name | John |
| 1 | key_2 | etc |

Query

```
 SELECT `user_id`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_1' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_1`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_2' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_2`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_3' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_3`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_4' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_4`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_5' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_5`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_6' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_6`,
 case when `meta_key`='key_7' then `meta_value` else '' end as `key_7`
 from
       (select `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`
         from `source_table`
        where `user_id`='1'
          and `meta_key` in     
            ('key_1','key_2','key_3','key_4','key_5','key_6','key_7')) x
 group by `user_id`
```

Result

| user_id | key_1 | key_2 | key_3 | key_4 | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John |  |  |  |  |

I can clearly see the problem is that it's taking the first value it finds and using that row to fill out the whole table.... what I don't know is how to stop it doing this.

Because the purpose of this pivot is to transform data for a transfer from one secure DB to another (no integration available), I don't really want to drop it into a spreadsheet as an interim step if I can avoid it.

Can someone advise...?

Comment: You've run afoul of MySQL's [nonstandard GROUP BY handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).  And, put a blank line before a Markdown table to make it render correctly.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks - I don't work in mySQL much. Some bedtime reading for tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
SELECT `user_id`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_1' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_1`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_2' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_2`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_3' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_3`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_4' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_4`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_5' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_5`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_6' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_6`,
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key_7' then `meta_value` else '' end) as `key_7`
 from
 (select `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value` from `source_table`
 where `user_id`='1' and `meta_key` in     ('key_1','key_2','key_3','key_4','key_5','key_6','key_7')) x
 group by `user_id
```

Comment: Hi @smallnorthumbrianvillage if my answer helps you please mark as accepted along with useful.

Comment: Thanks @smallnorthumbrianvillage. Please mark as accepted so that anyone make sure it is the exact answer which you want.