# Convert NULL into meaningful value with MAX function - mySQL

Tags: mysql, null, max

Can anybody please help me out with an incredibly frustrating line of code in mySQL.

This is a continuation of this case: ["Pivoting" a key|value table using case returns blank columns... mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755698/pivoting-a-keyvalue-table-using-case-returns-blank-columns-mysql/68755935)

The code provided in that sample works, but now I'm moving to production, there's one line I cannot get to work correctly. I suspect this is due to NULL values within the max clause, but I'm not sure of how to workaround.

I would like the troublesome line to be:

```
 MAX(case when `meta_key`='key1' and (`meta_value`='Validated' or `meta_value` is null) then 'Validated' else 'Not Validated' end) as `key1`
```

Ie, NULL = validated; Validated = Validated; Anything else = Not Validated.

**Updated**
It seems the issue is that the `null` is not caused by a corresponding key|value with the value being null, but by there *not being* a corresponding key|value pair for that user. This is creating odd results.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f2d9/1 for example.

Comment: MAX would always return validated as it is the max from validated and not validated, so i don't see what you expect, make a [mre] and show us what you are searching for

Comment: such pivot queries expect that youi ahve only 2 values the one you search and teh rest is NULL

Comment: @nbk That's helpful actually. It sounds like I need another stage in the query to transform the values, rather than doing it within the MAX / pivot.

Comment: Seems to work as I would expect here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee05c0/1

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for this, the cause is now clearer... it seems the issue is that the NULLs are caused by there not being a corresponding key|value pair. See [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f2d9/1) This represents what I'm seeing in my live data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work as you would like:

```
IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN `meta_key`='key1' AND `meta_value`<>'Validated' THEN'Not Validated' END), 
       'Validated') as `key1`
```

I've reversed your logic here, so anything that has a value for `key1` that is not validated will return `Not Validated`, anything else will return `NULL`. I then use `IFNULL()` to replace all `NULL`s with `Validated`

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/90f2d9/4)**