# Monthly Counter Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query. The query and its output can be found below.

[image]

Well, I need a query that takes this query as subquery and it will produce output like below. I prepared some queries but they didn't work, generaly they brought null for each month value. There might be another better apporach for this kind of problems. I have just tried like that.

[image]

Comment: Please check answer of this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68755698/pivoting-a-keyvalue-table-using-case-returns-blank-columns-mysql/68755935#68755935; Hopefully it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you will have to use something like `PIVOT()` in `SQL`. Unfortunately, it is not available in `MySQL`. So this will work:

```
SELECT customer, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='January' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='February' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='March' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='April' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='May' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS May,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='June' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='July' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Jul,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='August' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Aug,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='September' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Sep,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='October' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Oct,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='November' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Nov,
       MAX(CASE WHEN month='December' THEN total_count ELSE 0 END) AS Decem
FROM t
GROUP BY customer
```

**Note:**

- `t` must be replaced with your entire query as `sub-query`
- Taking `MAX`, `MIN` or `SUM` will give us the same result as it is already grouped at `month` and `customer` level
- If you wanna use `Dec` for last column name, use it as `"Dec"` otherwise MySQL will throw an error (due to keyword is used)

Look at the **Demo** in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b2fe2ebd032001ac15292074e02b0abc)*